# Performance of StructureMap with asp.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I use Structuremap (2.6.4.1) as IoC container in an asp.net MVC 4 project using WebApi too. It's plugged to the web site following best practices and nothing is really special here.

As I use *intensively* dependency resolution, I have around 500 definitions (This is the number of InstanceFactory instances in the main PipelineGraph).

Running a custom profiler localy or running load tests with asp.net profiler lead me to the same result :  GetNestedContainer is a CPU-consumming operation (around 25%). It's not something I think, It's something I've measured. From another basic test, a simple stopwatch around GetNestedContainer takes around 15ms (when my web api action take 40 ms).

GetNestedContainer is called only once in my code : in my/structuremap implementation of `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`.

```
public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
{
    IContainer child = this.Container.GetNestedContainer();
    return new StructureMapHttpDependencyResolver(child);
}
```

Just for the fun, after decompiling this code, I understand why it's so slow : lock, iteration over all InstanceFactories, and even reflexion (inside Clone)

```
//from structuremap
public PipelineGraph ToNestedGraph()
{
    PipelineGraph clone = new PipelineGraph(this._profileManager.Clone(), this._genericsGraph.Clone(), this._log)
    {
        _missingFactory = this._missingFactory
    };
    Monitor.Enter(this);
    try
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, IInstanceFactory> pair in this._factories)
        {
            clone._factories.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.Clone());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this);
    }
    clone.EjectAllInstancesOf<IContainer>();
    return clone;
}
```

When using asp.net web api, BeginScope is called for every request. As I have many ajax requests because of real-time display, I've a serious bottleneck. Is structureMap really compatible with asp.net Web Api ?

What can I do to improve this ?

The first idea that come to my mind is to reduce the number of InstanceFactory definitions. It's not so easy to do because I have many dependencies between my implementations. Even with 200 definitions, the impact will be important. Unfortunately, StructureMap seems to forbid multiple root containers (one for MVC, and one for WebApi).

Comment: What do you mean by Structuremap forbidding multiple root containers? `ObjectFactory` is just a default static container you can use if you don't want to handle juggling your own instance around. There is nothing preventing you from creating your own set of containers. Just call `new Container(c => { ...});` and create the containers you need.

Comment: @PHeiberg that's completely true. I was just using `ObjectFactory` as the default container factory. First try with multiple containers is promising. However, I'm still not confident about SM performance with a large number of bindings.